# Can't connect to H2 database in automatic mixed mode

Tags: java, h2

I have the following config in the persistence.xml of my jpa app:

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:c:/workdir/db/dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
<properties>
```

I suppose it's called 'Automatic Mixed Mode' and i should be able to access it using the jdbc:h2:file:c:/workdir/db/dev url in the h2 console.

I start the h2 console:

```
java -jar h2-1.3.172.jar -url jdbc:h2:file:c:/workdir/db/dev
```

Then i see only INFORMATION_SCHEMA and no tables created by my app.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's because the jpa app is using a different version of h2 jar. So the fix is to use the same versions of h2 jar everywhere.